# Hide search icon of ion-searchbar when start typing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

I am using ionic 6 and I am using ion-searchbar. **I want to hide the search icon once I start typing in it.**

Can anyone please help me how to achieve this.

```
 <ion-searchbar placeholder = "Search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" [formControl]="searchControl"
        (ionChange)="onIonChange()"></ion-searchbar>

  onIonChange() {
    if(this.searchText.length >= 1) {
      
    }
  }
```